# countdown.js giving incorrect time difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js for setting up a countdown text between a `fromDate` and a `toDate`. Below is my code snippet

```
var fromDate = new Date(2015, 01, 01);
var toDate = new Date(2015, 01, 02);
var countDown = countdown(fromDate, toDate).toString();
console.log(fromDate);
console.log(toDate);
console.log(countDown);
```

and I am getting the following output

```
Sat Feb 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
Sun Feb 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
-1 years, 11 months, and 30 days.
```

I have also tried to construct the `fromDate` and `toDate` like this

```
var fromDate = new Date("February 01, 2015 00:00:00");
```

but I am getting the same negative value. Am I doing anything wrong or is this an issue in `countdown.js` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the problem exactly but it works correctly when i use their code locally like this i am getting correct result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="countdown.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
var fromDate = new Date(2015, 01, 01);
var toDate = new Date(2015, 01, 02);
var countDown = countdown(fromDate, toDate).toString();
console.log(fromDate);
console.log(toDate);
console.log(countDown);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

copy the countdown.js code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js/src/bede3af6741d5ba6f12d97a4e2d5d97bae409532/countdown.js?at=default) and keep it locally.

**Result** what i am getting is

```
Date {Sun Feb 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
Date {Mon Feb 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)}
1 day
```

Comment: I was using an old version of countdown which had this problem. This problem is solved by using `v2.4.1` from this here - https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/countdown.js/src/bede3af6741d5ba6f12d97a4e2d5d97bae409532/countdown.js?at=default